# What's the difference between a sessionKey and a key container?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

I know how to export/import key containers in IIS using the `aspnet_regiis` command. Using that, I can export e.g. `iisConfigurationKey` that is used in `applicationHost.config` for the `AesProvider` and import the key container on another server.

But what I don't understand is how the `sessionKey` attribute on e.g. `AesProvider` fits into this. It looks nothing like the contents of an exported key container XML (it's not similar to the private nor the public key).

How is the `sessionKey` attribute generated (in correlation with the key container) and what is its purpose?